# angular property isnt known

Tags: angular, input

So I've searched around and I've found plenty of the same error messages but my problem doesn't seem to be identical to theirs since they're basically all lack of inclussion in the ng declarations. "Can't bind to 'posts' since it isn't a known property of 'app-post-list'."

My app component template has this:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<main>
  <app-post-create (postCreated)="onPostAdded($event)"></app-post-create>
  <hr>
  <app-post-list [posts]="storedPosts"></app-post-list>
</main>
```

ts:

```
export class AppComponent {
  storedPosts = [];

  onPostAdded(post) {
    this.storedPosts.push(post);
  }
}
```

post-list ts:

```
export class PostListComponent {

    @Input() posts = [];
}
```

How come that isn't a known property?

Comment: Is `app-post-list` 's component = `PostListComponent ` ?

Comment: Yes, PostListCompoent has a selector of app-post-list.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make your @Input public.

```
export class PostListComponent {

    @Input() public posts = [];
}
```

& your binding properties public too

```
export class AppComponent {
  public storedPosts = [];

  onPostAdded(post) {
    this.storedPosts.push(post);
  }
}
```

Comment: That was it, thanks. I'm from c# so I'm more than used to that but the course I'm taking didn't include it so I was a bit lost. Thanks man.

Comment: @PardonMyCheckmate as your issue is solved, please accept the answer

Comment: Yes, but I can't do that till 4 minutes. I will accept it then. I also upvoted you but that wont be public. Thanks again